# How to sort a mutablensarray?

Tags: xcode, sorting, nsmutablearray

I made this code to sort an nsmutablearray but how to send back an NSMutablearray ? i need this because a add information later in my mutablearray.

-(NSArray*)trierTableau:(NSMutableArray*)ptableau champsFiltre:(NSString*) champs{

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor =
[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
  initWithKey:champs
  ascending:YES
  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];

NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lastDescriptor, nil];
NSArray * sortedArray = [ptableau sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

return sortedArray;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort your `NSMutableArray` in-place, then you could call `sortUsingDescriptors:` instead of `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`, which returns a sorted copy of your array. `sortUsingDescriptors:` will sort the existing `NSMutableArray`.

e.g.

```
-(void)trierTableau:(NSMutableArray*)ptableau champsFiltre:(NSString*) champs {
    NSSortDescriptor *lastDescriptor =
    [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
      initWithKey:champs
      ascending:YES
      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];

    NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lastDescriptor, nil];
    [ptableau sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
}
```

This way you don't have to return the `NSMutableArray` either.

If you actually want a sorted copy of the array, then you'll need to create a new `NSMutableArray`, use `addObjectsFromArray:` to copy the elements over, and then use `sortUsingDescriptors:` on the new array. But I think that sorting the existing `NSMutableArray` is probably what you'll want.